# Firebase authentecation not working on my freenom domain

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I am using Reactjs with firebase SDK for authentication with google auth it's all working just fine on the development server link and also working on the link http://localhost:3000/ and also on firebase hosting link https://pro--student.web.app/ but when i access the website from the domain that i added to firebase hosting settings https://prostudent.ga the authentication does not work so i am pretty sure that the code is fine the problem is only somewhere on the domain can anyone help me solve this ?
this is the authentication code is you want it

```
auth.signInWithPopup(googleProvider)
    .then((result) => {
      // The signed-in user info.
      var user = result.user.providerData[0];
      store.dispatch({ type: actions.SIGNIN, payload: user });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert(error.message);
    });
```

and this is an image of my hosting infos https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mqWF.png

Comment: [MXToolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3aprostudent.ga&run=toolpage) is reporting an invalid DNS configuration for that domain. In the domains for Hosting, click that "View" button to complete the setup.

Comment: Yes, as @samthecodingman mentioned, even [DNS Checker](https://dnschecker.org/#TXT/prostudent.ga) won't show any DNS records. Firebase requires you to add a TXT record for verification as well as couple of A records while setting up a domain. Make sure you have them set up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/overview), ensure that your new custom domain is included in the list of [Authorized Domains](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/providers) in the Firebase Authentication section in addition to being listed in the [Project Domains](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/hosting/sites) in the Firebase Hosting section.

Comment: thank you so much. as you said the problem was in the authorized area where I did not add the newly added domain as a trusted domain. again thank you so much